# failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND management.azure.com

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hi stuck with this error for days when signing to azure-account in vscode. It always display the error

```
2023-11-15 13:50:00.453 [info] [Axios Response] 200 - POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
2023-11-15 13:50:00.463 [info] [Axios Request] POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
2023-11-15 13:50:01.179 [info] [Axios Response] 200 - POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
2023-11-15 13:50:01.186 [info] [SubscriptionsClient Request] GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01
2023-11-15 13:50:01.289 [error] request to https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01 failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND management.azure.com
```

BTW i am using my own corporate laptop and based on my research I think this is some DNS issue. I tried :

- flushing the dns cache,
- downgrading the azure-account extension from latest to previous version

I tried to sign-in in my personal computer and everything works fine. How can I solve this ? I appreciate all the help. Thank you

VScode proxy setting :
[image]

Comment: Are you able to signin to Azure via browser?

Comment: @PravallikaKV yes. I can sign.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of proxy settings of your vscode.

Comment: I don't have any configuration on my proxy settings in vs code. I edited my post to add the screenshot

Comment: Enable [Http.proxyStrictSSL](https://i.imgur.com/mhEiBzk.png).

Answer (score 0):

It happens if your corporate network has blocked the proxy to `SignIn to Azure`.

To resolve this, you can set **HTTPS_PROXY** in the environment variable to allow the **VSCode** and **browser** to open up the Azure Sign in the login page.

- Run the below commands in Terminal to set the **Https_Proxy** and **Http_Proxy**  in environment variable:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
```

(or)

- Open `VSCode=>Settings=>Proxy` and set the proxy in `Http:Proxy`.
- Check `Http:Proxy Strict SSL`.

[image]

- Install [Network Proxy Test extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrmarti.network-proxy-test) in VSCode to test the network settings and connection.

Open `VSCode=> Command Palette(F1/ctrl+shift+P)=>` search for **Network Proxy Test: Test Connection**, enter proxy and test the connection.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me to solve this problem. I tried running the commands you've gaved to set up the http_proxy env variables and tried to test the network connection. However I received this error while testing the network connection : 

[ Sending GET request to http://username:password@proxy:8080...
Received error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy (ENOTFOUND) ]

Comment: You have to modify the command with your proxy.

Comment: Or you can use `set HTTP_PROXY=localhost, <portnumber>` && `HTTPS_PROXY=localhost, <portnumber>`. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/rjmKtml.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a resent issue in azure. I manage to resolve it by updating their current version. [github issue link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/894#issuecomment-1816662267)